# CentOS 7.x on GNOME how to modify default terminal

Tags: debian, centos, terminal, terminal-emulator

I have CentOS 7.6.1810 with 'server with GUI' option selected at install time. I also installed terminator, I am looking for a way to change the default terminal on CentOS to become terminator, I tried the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

The above does nothing on CentOS, but it works OK on Debian and Ubuntu:

```
myuser@Debian:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
sudo: unable to resolve host Debian: Temporary failure in name resolution
[sudo] password for oshaker: 
There are 6 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Any clues on CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS doesn't use the 'alternatives' system for 'x-terminal-emulator'.  You can tell GNOME to launch a particular terminal emulator when it asks for it (as the other answer provideS), but it won't change any of the launchers in the menu.

Comment: I better stick with debian then as it provides what I need, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following command to switch it to assumeng you have it already installed if not execute the following command: `sudo yum install terminator`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working, terminal is still gnome-terminal

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a soft link like `ln -s /usr/bin/terminator <default-terminal-path>`?

Comment: And what is the ''default-terminal-path''?